# Bash prompt coloring not appearing correctly

Tags: bash, prompt

I had a functioning Bash prompt colored how I wanted it, but after reinstalling the background is gray rather than black like this setting should make it.
My `PS1` is

```
\[\e[33;40m\]\T \[\e[36;1m\]\u\[\e[31;40m\]@\[\e[32;1m\]\h \W> \[\e[0m\]
```

Below is a screenshot for clarification. I am talking about the gray behind the prompt.

[image: 05:54:03 alex@localhost ~>]

Comment: Side note: `\e[;0m` is redudant -- either `\e[m` or `\e[0m` is enough (as an empty parameter means exactly the same as `0`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your terminal's color scheme has dark gray in its "black" slot. (The rest of the terminal is actually black because the *default* background is a completely separate slot.) This used to be the default setting in GNOME Terminal until version 3.12.

Go to "Edit → Profile Preferences", open the "Color" tab, find the 16 color scheme slots, and change the "Black" slot to have actual black.

(Alternatively, don't request black background in the prompt *in the first place*. There's no need to do so since your current prompt never changes the background *from* black anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

I used the ["List of colors for prompt and Bash"](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt#List_of_colors_for_prompt_and_Bash) from the ArchWiki, and came up with this:

```
txtylw='\e[0;33m' # Yellow
txtred='\e[0;31m' # Red
bldcyn='\e[1;36m' # Bold Cyan
bldgrn='\e[1;32m' # Bold Green
txtrst='\e[0m'    # Text Reset
PS1="${txtylw}\T ${bldcyn}\u${txtred}@${bldgrn}\h \W>${txtrst} "
```

The result:

[image: Terminal session with colored Bash prompt]